# UIMA Ruta input type - html

Tags: uima, ruta

I have pdf and word files that need to be used as an input for Ruta. I can convert them into text files, but lose all the tables and formatting if I do that. Is there anyway I can use them without losing any information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional program that is able to convert pdf (/doc/docx) to html. There are mainly two different types of PDF converter: those which use absolute positions for generating nice-looking html, and those which rely only on html elements and css. For processing tables, I recommend the latter ones. I personally use a commerical solution, but there is also a lot of good open source software, e.g., [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX)

If you have html, then you can apply the HtmlAnnotator and HtmlConverter for gaining plain text with annotations for the html tags as described in the [UIMA Ruta documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#section.tools.ruta.howto.html)

Comment: Thanks Peter! May I know which commercial solutions you would recommend for word and pdf files? 
We used adobe professional ones , but they create htmls that are not compatible with Ruta.

Comment: My experience concerning Word/docx is outdated. PDF: I evaluated Adobe Pro, Nuance Omnipage, Abbyy finereader amonst others. Each has different advantages. Currently, I use Datalogics PDF Alchemist.

Comment: Why is the html of adobe not compatible?